# Nextjs Unable to setState after async function call

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs Form with fields like FirstName , Age and place to Upload Image.
After populating the form and uploading the image( saving uploaded File in the state variable using URL.createObjectURL() at this moment, works fine), i want to do the below steps :

1. First upload the image from state variable to cloudinary server.
2. After upload is complete, fetch the image url and setForm with rest of the fields.

   ```
            //helper function to upload images to Cloudinary server
            uploadImageToCloudinary(imageFile)
            .then((res)=>{

                setForm({
                    ...form,
                    "picUploaded" : "true", //hard coded value for testing
                    "profilePic" : res.url //url is retrieved here successfully
                });

                //run validationafter upload to make sure required fields are there
                let errs = validate();
                setError(errs);
            })
   ```

Validation Code

```
    const validate= () => {
    console.log(form.picUploaded);// Output : true
    let err = {};
    if(!form.firstName){
      err.firstName= 'First Name is required.';
    }
    if(!form.lastName){
      err.lastName= 'Last Name is required.';
    }

    if(!form.profilePic){ //Issue : Profile pic is not set here
      err.profilePic= 'Profile Pic is required.';
    }

    return err;
 }
```

Issue : The uploaded image url is not set in the form(field profilePic), but a hardcoded value picUploaded is set.
Can someone please guide me on what am i missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you run the validation right after the setForm call, it's async so your validation will hit previous form values, not the new ones.

To avoid this you would need to run validation separately like so.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setError(validate())      
}, [form])
```

that will run validation on every form update, which is something you may or may not want, depending on the use case.

```
   uploadImageToCloudinary(imageFile)
     .then((res)=>{

         setForm({
             ...form,
             "picUploaded" : "true", //hard coded value for testing
             "profilePic" : res.url //url is retrieved here successfully
         });
     })
```